# Sending data entries from application on tablet to database stored elsewhere

Tags: android, android-sqlite

My current conundrum is this. I understand well enough how to store data inside an application itself, but my current goal is to have each data entry created by the app to be immediately sent to a server located elsewhere. What would be the best method for achieving that?

Apologising in advance for the vague question, I just don't know where to start.

Comment: an internet search would get you started...

Comment: I did try, but my google-fu must not be strong enough because I couldn't find a relevant link. It was not my intention to use you as a search engine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Send data via HTTP to a PHP enabled webserver that can write the data to a database.

Answer (score 1):

Try researching on these:

REST and SOAP.

You can also try API and XML.

REST and SOAP are protocols for data interchange.

API is Application Programming Interface, you can build one yourself on the server or see if the server application have it already.

XML is the data format that is generally used for data exchange.